# Logon Script Delay

Tags: authentication, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, gpo

I'm running a Windows Server 2012 R2, and I've deployed a logon script for my domain, although I've configured the Logon Script Delay to ENABLED ("0" MINUTES), my script still taking the 5 minutes to run after my users log on to their machines!

So what am I missing here to get rid of the 5 minutes delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just researched this.  It appears that based on the most pertinent article I read (linked at the end of this answer), you are doing this correctly, based on this statement:  "If you enter the time in minutes as zero (0), the setting is disabled, and the Group Policy client runs the logon scripts at user logon without any delay."  That is exactly what you did. But your script is still waiting five minutes before executing.

The article does offer another statement presenting another way of achieving your goal:  "If you want the logon scripts to run at user logon without any delay, you should configure the setting to Disabled:"

> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy:
>   Configure Logon Script Delay ==> Disabled

Also look into the fact that since this is a computer setting, ensure your computer resides within an OU to which the GPO is linked, that there is no security or WMI filtering at work excluding your computer, and that there is no other over-riding GPO to this policy, and that the GPO is not being blocked.  You can run a command to see why the GPO setting may not be applying if this or something else is blocking it:

```
gpresult /H gporeport.html
```

Reference:  [Logon scripts do not run for five minutes after a user logs on to a Windows 8.1-based computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2895815/logon-scripts-do-not-run-for-five-minutes-after-a-user-logs-on-to-a-windows-8.1-based-computer)

Comment: hey T-Heron, your answer is awesome! I think it will solve the problem, let me get to test and I'll be back to share the results! but i want to thank you in advance!